# Returning dynamic values onclick in javascript

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate depending upon the data returned onclick using python and selenium.

This is the html code

```
<li id="Region" title="Region" val="1" onclick="hierarchyChangedCommand(this); return false;" sname="Input" class="groupItem">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</li>
<li id="Product" title="Product" val="2" onclick="hierarchyChangedCommand(this); return false;" sname="Input" class="groupItem">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</li>
```

hierarchyChangedCommand returns dynamic hierarchy depending upon Region clicked or Product clicked. How do i get the hierarchy values. New to python and selenium. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: When you click either of these items, you need to find _where_ the new data is returned to and which field gets populated, such as a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

There is other way 
After selecting the product call 'hierarchyChangedCommand()'

```
data = wd.execute_script("hierarchyChangedCommand()")
```

Comment: wd.find_element_by_id('Product').click()
data = wd.execute_script("hierarchyChangedCommand()") Getting javascript error.

Comment: It realy hard to find out why its giving the error because I dont have access to your app. Try to fire javascript first and hold product click.

Comment: this is passed to the hierarchyChangedCommand in the html so do i need to pass anything instead of just empty parameter.

Comment: How can I tell you ? I have no clue what it does or what it need as input ? 
You have issue about how to get value from javascript method, I have suggested a solution. 
Rest depend on your webpage and how its designed,